# Azure Devops - Notify a user when a work item is completed

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is it possible within Azure devops to send a bespoke notification to a user when a work item is completed.

Example Scenario

1. Work item are logged in azure devops under project by user 'Y' on behalf of a user 'X'
2. When this work item is completed is it possible to automate an email to user 'X'. Saying something like your request has been completed.

User 'Y' = Member of development team
User 'X' = End user of system, who has requested feature

Is this possible to achieve or is there a better way to go about this process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is possible but azure devops should detect your X by some properties. I see two ways:

1. User X may to [Follow a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/follow-work-items?view=azure-devops#follow-a-work-item).
2. User Y may create some specific tag and you can create a custom notification for that tag:
   [image]

Or create a custom application that will scan your work items and send notifications.